# Filling an array with one field of data from a DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

I've got a DataTable with data in it.  For simplification, I'll say my DataTable looks like this:

```
DataTable AccDT = new DataTable();

string CmdTxt = "Select CBL.BENEFIT_ID as BenefitID, ";
CmdTxt = CmdTxt + "CBL.BENEFIT_CATEGORY as Category, CBL.BENEFIT_PROVISION as Provision, ";
CmdTxt = CmdTxt + "FROM CSTAPP_O.D_Benefit CBL ";

OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(CmdTxt, connection);
cmd.Connection = connection;

cmd.CommandText = CmdTxt;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);

da.Fill(AccDT);
```

Now, I want to fill an array with just the values of the field called "Category".  How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should put the column values into an array.

```
AccDT.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("Category")).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your array is a string,

```
for (int i = 0; i < AcctDT.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    someArray[i] = AcctDT.Rows[i]["Category"].ToString();
}
```

You can simply refer to columns by their name.